# Why is PHP rename($file) still deleting files?

Tags: php, directory, rename, delete-file

So I'm using the php rename function to systematically rename all the files in a specific folder.

According to the output buffer, it works fine.
When I look in the folder, it is missing files 11-99. I replaced the rename function with my own function below, however I am getting the exact same results.

Code:

```
function rename_files($directory){
  $path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\email' . '\\' . $directory . '\\';

  $x = 00001;

 foreach (glob($path."*") as $filename) {
     $newFile = $path . 'list' . $x . '.txt';
     $content = file_get_contents($filename); //this function returns the content of a file.
     echo "$newFile and old $filename<br>";
     unlink($filename);

     $file = fopen($newFile, "w");
     fwrite($file,$content);
     fclose($file);
     ++$x;
  }
}
```

Output:
[image: PHP Output Buffer]

Reality:

[image: Actual Files Created In The Folder]

Comment: "So I'm using the php rename function" but your not, you are using a poorly constructed diy approach rather than http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: Why are you assigning $x with the value `1` suffixed with four zeros?

Comment: I have the feeling you're overwriting existing files, could you try to _append_ all content and see if that's the case?

Comment: I started out using rename() and it has the EXACT same results. So I tried this "poorly constructed diy approach" after I read the php manual. The php.net manual gave me the same results as well. I thought I was rewriting files too, so I changed all the new files to append an 'a' to avoid this. It is still missing random files.

Comment: Philipp has a point, you're generating and feeding new files to the rename (again)...

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is, that your source and destination directory is the same and the names of the old files and new files are overlapping.

Looking at the first two lines of your output should show you the problem. The newly created file list1.txt is deleted in the second loop iteration.

A simple, but working solution for your problem should be to create a new directory where you move and rename all files (`rename` should work for this) and later delete the now empty source directory and replace it with the temporary one.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your new filenames are the same as old filenames.

You renamed `list103 (2).txt` to `list11.txt`. This overwrote the original `list11.txt`. Later, you renamed `list11.txt` to `list25.txt`.

As a result, the original `list11.txt` is lost.

This happens over and over: `list1 (2).txt -> list1.txt -> list2.txt`

You need to check whether `$newFile` already exists, and use a different name that doesn't exist. Or perhaps use different naming conventions for the old and new files, so that they can't conflict with each other.